# Solr subquery transformation

Tags: solr, solr6

I have a created solr core named `data`.
This core has two structurally different types of data:
playlist and album (actual tracks). Relation is

playlist has 1...* album
playlist

while retrieving playlist info, I want to retrieve album info in the same doc.
I tried this

```
Query
q=playlist_id:XXXXX

Field List
fl=*,album_info:[subquery]

rawQueryParam:
album_info.q={!terms f=album_unique_id v=$row.album_id}
```

This means I want to retrieve album_unique_id which is the album_id in playlist.

I studied Solr doc and created above query. But not getting the required result. I get an exception in the response:

```
{
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError"],
    "msg":"while invoking album_info.q:[subquery] on doc=SolrDocument{album_unique_id =stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS<album_unique_id:20-3-108-10080",
    "code":400}}
```

Need to understand the reason for this error. Also, do I need to enable some plugin for this?

solr version: v6.4

Comment: Hmmm...  There are a few things I'm unsure of there...  Are you using the Admin Console to do this?  If yes can you add the URL that results and possibly a screenshot of the Admin Console before you press the search button?

Comment: Yes I am searching using admin. I guess it has something to do with the UI of solr admin console. Not sure right now. Also, does subquery transformation has an option for nesting till n level as we have in mysql

Comment: Please issue the query on the Admin UI and post the URL that results (you'll find it just above the results in the Admin UI after they return)